# Remove width attribute after JQuery Width animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am animating the reduction of a `<section>`'s width from a fluid .span12 to match the width of .span3.
How I'm currently doing it is:

```
$('#searchPanel').animate({width: '23.404255317%'}, 400);
$('#searchPanel').removeClass('span12');
$('#searchPanel').addClass('span3');
```

Problem is, the width set in the animation is overriding the .span3 class. Which is messing up some responsive stuff I have going on.

How do I get rid of that width after animating it? I know that jquery ui has .switchclass but I'm thinking I'm just doing this in a dumb way and should know how to do things like this...

Thank you!

Update: 
It might not be the best solution, but I got it to work by adding a callback and removing the 'Style' Attribute:

```
$('#searchPanel').animate({width: '23.404255317%'}, 400, 'swing', function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('style').removeClass('span12').addClass('span3');
 } );
```

Comment: a fiddle will help you get solution fast

Comment: Thanks, the update helped solve my problem. You should add it as a solution and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$('#searchPanel')
.animate({width: '23.404255317%'}, 400)
.removeClass('span12')
.addClass('span3')
.removeAttr('width');
```

Also, remember to search only once for the element $('#searchPanel") and then chain the others methods.

Comment: Thank you for the chaining tip! That's going to clean up my code a lot. I figured it out, I needed to put all of that inside a callback. and instead of removing 'width' I needed to remove 'style'

Comment: you are right, I forgot about the callback in animate, also you should consider the animation queue in jQuery, in the case that de event is trigered multiple times.